# Why the following use of Google translator python API does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-translate

```
from googletrans import Translator

foreign_word = "Montag"
t = Translator()
translated_word = t.translate(foreign_word, src='de', dest='en').text
print(translated_word) # Expecting "Monday", but prints "Montag"
```

I called the code snipped above multiple times for different German words. In the beginning, the translator was working, but now whenever I try to execute the code above, the `translated_word` is always identical (character by character) to the `foreign_word`.

**Question:** Am I using the API incorrectly or can you translate a limited number of times per day/hour?

The command-line version does not seem to work either:

```
translate "Montag" -s de -d en
[en] Montag
    ->
[en] Montag
[pron.] Montag
```

I am using Python 3.8.5

Comment: The Docs (https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#googletrans.Translator.translate) says that the argument is `dest` not `dst`.

Comment: @SvenEberth thanks for the catch, I updated it to `dest`, the problem still remains though.

Comment: I can observe the same behavior right now. The first translations worked fine. And now I receive the source word. Seems to be a kind of rate limit by google -- obviously they want you to pay for the translation API :/
There's is already a related issue: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/290

Comment: I think this module doesn't use official API but unoffical url to get translation - and Google may block it. In source code I found `https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single` but it doesn't look like url for official API. Official API may need own `client_ID` and `client_secret` and it needs to register own applications in Google.

Comment: @furas You're totally right. I think I have expressed myself somewhat unclearly. They use the Ajax API (that's used by the Translator site translate.google.com itself). But google don't want that you use this API by your own, so they limit the requests. So unfortunately  you have to use the official one for many requests (where you have to pay for).

Answer (score 0):

The API in question might be outdated, the following API worked for me:

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator

translator = google_translator()
word = "Montag"
translation = translator.translate(word, lang_tgt='en')
print(translation) # prints Monday
```

If you call `translator.translate` too frequently, you will get an error `HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url`, so you might need to batch your requests into a `not_too_large_list` and call `translator.translate(not_too_large_list, lang_tgt='en')`